# Possible to access My.Forms object in VB.NET class library?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to access the `My.Forms` object in a `VB.NET` class library?

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87y2hdsf(v=vs.80).aspx

Similar question here: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/146962.aspx

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87y2hdsf.aspx) `My.Forms` is only available if your project type is Windows Application. It's not available for other project types, including class library.

Also, please note that

> the My.Forms object exposes only the forms associated with the current project.

So when you use it in a Windows Application project, it will only give you access to forms created within the same project.

Comment: Updated my answer to clarify that `My.Forms` isn't in fact available in a class library.